# Exchenge 2010 server is not finding GC server in the domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, exchange-2010, domain-controller

Exchenge 2010 server is not finding GC server in the domain even the domain controler . All Domain controllers are Windows Server 2012 Std.  In the atest.local forest I have 3 DC and all 3 are GC:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.atest> get-adforest atest.local
ApplicationPartitions : {DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=atest,DC=local, DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=atest,DC=local,
                        DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=cot,DC=atest,DC=local}
CrossForestReferences : {}
DomainNamingMaster    : pdc2-v.atest.local
Domains               : {atest.local, cot.atest.local}
ForestMode            : Windows2003Forest
GlobalCatalogs        : {cot2-v.cot.atest.local, pdc2-v.atest.local, pdc3-v.atest.local}
Name                  : atest.local
PartitionsContainer   : CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=atest,DC=local
RootDomain            : atest.local
SchemaMaster          : pdc2-v.atest.local
Sites                 : {Default-First-Site-Name}
SPNSuffixes           : {}
UPNSuffixes           : {}
```

But on the Exchange 2010 side in the EventViewer I see the following message generated by ADTopology exchenge process:

```
Process STORE.EXE (PID=5740). Exchange Active Directory Provider has discovered the following servers with the following characteristics: 
 (Server name | Roles | Enabled | Reachability | Synchronized | GC capable | PDC | SACL right | Critical Data | Netlogon | OS Version) 
In-site:
cot2-v.cot.atest.local  CDG 1 7 7 1 0 1 1 7 1
pdc2-v.atest.local  CD- 1 6 7 0 0 0 1 7 1
pdc3-v.atest.local  CD- 1 6 7 0 0 0 1 7 1
```

which means that DCs pdc3-v.atest.local  and pdc2-v.atest.local are not identified by ADTopology process as a GC. Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 0 instead of 1 under 'SACL right' on the problem servers.  This is an error condition that I've seen discussed in a few places, such as [this technet blogpost.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/richardroddy/2010/06/16/msexchange-adaccess-dsaccess-errors-and-the-manage-auditing-and-security-right/)

I believe re-running `Setup /PrepareAD` should resolve that.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you rather than commenting - see: http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers